# How long would it take to guess a correct card from a deck two times in a row?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

How long would it take to guess a correct card two times in a row?

Let's say I have a choice to make, call it A, B, C, D, E.  Let's say I decide to let fortune pick for me.  I take a deck of cards numbered 1-100.  I go through the letters in order, and I select a random card a guess its number and turn it over.  Example: "For choice A, number 23."  If it's wrong, I shuffle the deck, say the next letter in the sequence and guess another numbered card. Example: "For choice B, number 88."  If it comes up correct (1:100), then I attempt attempt to "confirm" that choice by attempting to guess correctly immediately after my first correct guess, after shuffling and adding in 100 more cards.  Thus, the confirmation guess is a 200 card deck numbered 1-200.  Example: "To confirm choice A, number 123."  Let's assume each guess takes 5 seconds.  If the letter is not confirmed, I go back to selecting letters and guessing numbers in the 100 card deck.

Now to further complicate it.  Let's assume I arrive at choice "A" after a given period of time but I'm not satisfied.  I want to further "confirm" that choice by doing the exact process again, but this time only offering choices A, B, or C.  Guessing a correct card twice in a row (first in the 100 card deck and secondly in a 200 card deck) would confirm the lettered choice.  If choice A is not confirmed, I go all the way back to the beginning with 5 choices.  How long does it take until choice A (or any letter) is confirmed twice in a row through both the 1/5 test and the 1/3 test.

Please help me calculate how long each step and the entire process ought to take from a probability standpoint.   Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze the first step. The probability of confirming is basically $\frac{1}{100} \times \frac{1}{200}= \frac{1}{20000}$. From that, you would expect to take $20000$ guesses before confirming a choice.

Afterwards, though, you want to re-confirm. Probability of confirming any option is still $\frac{1}{20000}$, but when you do that, only $\frac {1}{3}$ of the time you'll confirm the same choice as before. So, in mean, you'll have to repeat the whole process three times to have a success.

To sum up, you have to make, in mean, $(20000 + 20000) \times 3 = 120000 $ guesses. If each guess takes 5 seconds, everything will take $\frac{120000}{60\times 60} \approx 33.3$ hours.

Good luck with your guessing.

Edited to solve the mistake pointed out by Lucas

Comment: Help me understand: Since both tests are independent events confirming a single choice, wouldn't they be added together then times 3?  Since test one is independently 20000 choices, test two has a 1/3 chance of confirming test one.  So = 3(20000 + 20000) guesses.  I don't know the right formula, but broken down I came up with:  A (20k), then A or B or C (20k), if rejected, A (20k), then A or B or C (20k), if rejected, A (20k), then A or B or C (20k).  That's 3 times so the proability of getting it right = 20000 x 6 = 3(20000 + 20000).  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lucas You're right, my mistake. What a big one, actually. Thanks.

Comment: Well, without your help and explanation, I would never have gotten this far to begin with.  My initial calculations were way off.  So if I'm following your formula correctly, probability would say on average 100 hours @ the rate of 3 seconds per choice?